# Call upon specific elements from array

Tags: arrays, perl, bioinformatics

Ok, so I have a bunch of file names possessing one of the following two formats:

Sample-ID_Adapter-Sequence_L001_R1_001.fastq (As Forward)

Sample-ID_Adapter-Sequence_L001_R2_001.fastq (As Reverse)

The only difference between the forward and reverse formats is the R1 and R2 elements in the filename. Now, I've managed to enable the user to provide the directory containing these files with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#Print Directory

print "Please provide the directory containing the FASTQ files from your Illumina MiSeq run \n";
my $FASTQ = <STDIN>;
chomp ($FASTQ);

#Open Directory

my $dir = $FASTQ;
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Cannot open $dir: $!";
my @forwardreads = grep { /R1_001.fastq/ } readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

my $direct = $FASTQ;
opendir(DIR, $direct) or die "Cannot open $dir: $!";
my @reversereads = grep { /R2_001.fastq/ } readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

foreach my $ffile (@forwardreads) {
    my $forward = $ffile;
    print $forward;
    }

foreach my $rfile (@reversereads) {
    my $reverse = $rfile;
    print $reverse;
    }
```

## The Problem

What I want to do with the above script is to find a way to pair up the elements of both arrays that are derived from the same Sample ID. Like I said, the only difference between the forward and reverse files (from the same sample ID) would be the R1 and the R2 parts of the file name.

I've tried looking up ways to extract elements from an array, but I want to let the program do the matching instead of me.

Thanks for reading and I hope you guys can help!

Comment: Could you provide your code as plain text? Just cut & paste it into your post, highlight it, and click the `{}` "Code Sample" button. If you can't get the formatting right, someone will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for that! There's the code all ready!

Comment: If all you want to do is find the pairs, you don't need to do it in the perl script. Just pipe the output to a couple extra unix commands like this (assuming there's 3 underscores before the R1/2 portion of the file names): `your_script.pl | cut -d '_' -f 1,2,3 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`.  All your pairs will be at the bottom.  You could grep them out too if you wanted and clip off the leading spaces/numbers. You could also do the equivalent of this in perl. It's not efficient, but it's simple and almost always more than sufficient.

Comment: It's not relevant to your question, but I'd suggest using `glob` rather than `readdir` and `grep`. e.g. `my @forwardreads = glob ( '*R1_001.fastq" );`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll have to parse out the filename. Fortunately, this is pretty straightforward. After stripping the extension, you can [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) the pieces on `_`.

```
# Strip the file extension.
my($suffix) = $filename =~ s{\.(.*?)$}{};

# Parse Sample-ID_Adapter-Sequence_L001_R1_001
my($sample_id, $adapter_sequence, $uhh, $format, $yeah) = split /_/, $filename;
```

Now you can do what you like with them.

I'd suggest a few things to improve the code.  First, put that filename parsing into a function so it can be reused and to keep the main code simpler.  Second, parse the filenames into a hash rather than a bunch of scalars, it'll be easier to work with and pass around.  Finally, include the filename itself in that hash, then the hash contains the complete data.  This, btw, is a gateway drug to OO programming.

```
sub parse_fastq_filename {
    # Read the next (in this case first and only) argument.
    my $filename = shift;

    # Strip the suffix
    my($suffix) = $filename =~ s{\.(.*?)$}{};

    # Parse Sample-ID_Adapter-Sequence_L001_R1_001
    my($sample_id, $adapter_sequence, $uhh, $format, $yeah) = split /_/, $filename;

    return {
        filename            => $filename,
        sample_id           => $sample_id,
        adapter_sequence    => $adapter_sequence,
        uhh                 => $uhh,
        format              => $format,
        yeah                => $yeah
    };
}
```

Then rather than finding left and right formatted files separately, process everything in one loop.  Put matching left and right pairs in a hash.  Use `glob` to pick up only the `.fastq` files.

```
# This is where the pairs of files will be stored.
my %pairs;

# List just the *.fastq files
while( my $filename = glob("$FASTQ_DIR/*.fastq")) {
    # Parse the filename into a hash reference
    my $fastq = parse_fastq_filename($filename);

    # Put each parsed fastq filename into its pair
    $pairs{ $fastq->{sample_id} }{ $fastq->{format} } = $fastq;
}
```

Then you can do what you like with `%pairs`. Here's an example to print out each sample ID and what formats it has.

```
# Iterate through each sample and pair.
# $sample is a hash ref of format pairs
for my $sample (values %pairs) {
    # Now iterate through each pair in the sample
    for my $fastq (values %$sample) {
        say "$fastq->{sample_id} has format $fastq->{format}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I placed your suggested code after deleting the "foreach" components of my script. I'm getting the error "use of uninitialized value $filename in substitution (s///)" within the subroutine. This error also applies for the split. Was I supposed to keep the foreach element in my code? 

Also, I have the following unix command where I want to call upon both elements of the pair separately. Could I call each element of the pair after setting them as you suggested?

Comment: @Postan92 What are you putting into `$filename`? Sounds like you never assigned anything to it. As for what you can do with `%pairs`, go nuts!

Comment: In the subroutine, I called my `$filename` as `shift @reads`. Outside of the subroutine, near the end of the script, I copied your suggestion with the pairs.

Comment: @Postan92 I don't know what `@reads` is, there's probably nothing in it. You don't literally have `my $filename = shift @reads` in the subroutine, do you? That would render the subroutine much less useful, reading from a specific global. Instead you should be doing something like `for my $filename (@reads) { my $fastq = parse_fastq_filename($filename); ... }`, passing filenames into the routine, and leave `my $filename = shift;` in the routine.

Comment: Sorry I'm really slow with this, but if I called `my $filename = shift` within the subroutine, it doesn't call upon any array, since the array I called was outside the subroutine's scope (I asked the user to input the directory containing all the files of interest at the start of the script). That's the only problem I'm having with the script.

Comment: `shift` *in a subroutine* is the same as `shift @_`. `@_` is the list of arguments passed to the subroutine. So `my $filename = shift` is the idiom to read the next argument (in this case the first and only argument) to the subroutine. This is why you have to pass filenames into the subroutine.